# OpenPyXl - TypeError: cannot unpack non-iterable NoneType object

Tags: python-3.x, openpyxl

I'm looking to find the first blank Cell value in an Excel row - then pass the numerical coords for that (I.e `'B2' = 2,2`) back to a variable.

If the cell has a value - then it's fine and the coords are returned. I've tested this by using:

```py
for row in sta_wb_primetime.iter_rows(min_row=start_row, max_row=end_row, min_col=start_col):
        for cell in row:
            ***if cell.value is not None:***
                return cell.row, cell.column`
```

However when I run the proper code block:

```py
#Find start point for Excel pasting (Master File)

def find_start_col(start_row, end_row, start_col):
    for row in wb.iter_rows(min_row=start_row, max_row=end_row, min_col=start_col):
        for cell in row:
            if cell.value is None:
                return cell.row, cell.column
            break
        else:
            continue  # only executed if the inner loop did NOT break
        break  # only executed if the inner loop DID break


sun_row, sun_col = find_start_col(start_row=3, end_row=3, start_col=2)
mon_row, mon_col = find_start_col(start_row=12, end_row=12, start_col=2)
```

`... (ongoing for rest of week)`

I get this:

> Traceback (most recent call last):
>     File "C:/Users/mattj/Desktop/Python Scripts/ScratchPad/dev_scripts/tester_file.py", line 49, in 
>       sun_row, sun_col = find_start_col(start_row=3, end_row=3, start_col=2)
>   TypeError: cannot unpack non-iterable NoneType object

All I need is to find the first blank cell on row 3 - then return the coords

Answer (score 0):

Think I've found a workaround. Openpyxl seems to not like returning results when the value is None - but seems ok to `contine` when `not None` and return the results as an `else` condition.

```
for row in wb.iter_rows(min_row=start_row, max_row=end_row, min_col=start_col):
    for cell in row:
        # print(cell)
        if cell.value is not None:
            continue
        else:
            return cell.row, cell.column
    else:
        continue  # only executed if the inner loop did NOT break
```

Hope this helps someone else! Would still love to know how reversing the conditions leads to a successful result

Thanks all